# Create WPA2 Enterprise Wifi + Certificate Apple Device Configuration Profile Without a Mac?

Tags: ios, configuration-profiles

I am fully aware that in the recent times, Apple has moved from the IPhone Configuration Utility to the Apple Configurator that is available on Mac only.

I, unfortunately, don't have a Mac, but I have a few WPA2-Enterprise networks that I need to create a configuration profile for.  I have Windows and Linux systems at my disposal, is there a way to create a configuration profile that works with recent iOS versions *without* the Apple Configurator, and if so, how would I go about doing that?

***NOTE:*** Any solution needs to support adding certificates *and* WPA2-Enterprise networks.  This is not available everywhere!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I completely forgot about this post, oops.

I took the plunge and followed [this tutorial](https://techsviewer.com/how-to-install-mac-os-x-el-capitan-on-vmware-on-pc/) to run Mac OS X on a VMware VM.  From there, I was able to upgrade it to macOS, and now have access to the App Store for Mac.

While this causes some headaches from a licensing perspective, I personally have now been able to use Apple Configurator via my Apple ID and that VM to create the configuration profile I was after.

---

Other MDM solutions posed in the other answers do not work for me - I already have MDM installed and configured because of my workplace using Mobile Iron and BYOD; that results in me being unable to use most MDM SaaS solutions to set up my device settings.

Answer (score 1):

**Mobile Device Management.**

Mobile device management allows you to remotely deploy profiles, and many let you create basic profiles in the web interface. You'll need to chat with several companies to find one that suits your needs.

Basically, all you have to do is install a premade profile on all the devices you need, then you're free to create a profile online.

The only downside to this approach is that many of the better solutions require payment. I know **SimpleMDM, Miradore, [Jamf NOW](https://www.jamf.com/products/jamf-now/)** and many others give free trials.

Comment: Neither of the solutions you suggested provide 802.1X WPA2-Enterprise or Certificate support.

Comment: @ThomasWard I've added Jamf Now - it's quite fully featured and also free to trial for a few devices.

Answer (score 1):

[Codeproof MDM](http://www.codeproof.com) supports WPA2-Enterprise WiFi configurations and they offer 14 days free trial of the software.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not the answer everybody is looking for, but configuration profiles are basically just XML files. Therefore, they can be created and edited with a simple text editor. That's definitely not the most comfortable way to do it, but it still works if you are limited on tools.

There is an [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/business/documentation/Configuration-Profile-Reference.pdf) that contains all available settings. For WPA2-Enterprise, go to page 110 and look for the "EAPClientConfiguration Dictionary" section.

Answer (score 0):

You could also run a piece of software that allows you to emulate macOS. YouTube is full of tutorials on how to do this. This way you won't have to pay for some MDM software, or buy any new hardware. Hope this helps!

Comment: Examples, please.

Comment: You could run some software like VirtualBox, and therefore have simulated macOS. From there, you could open the Apple App Store, and install Apple Configurator 2. Then you could just (hopefully) plug in your devices and install profiles that do what you want. Hope this helps. If you have any questions, just let me know. Here is a link to a tutorial to install macOS on Windows using virtualBox: http://lifehacker.com/5938332/how-to-run-mac-os-x-on-any-windows-pc-using-virtualbox